# pandas: rolling with periodic boundaries

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation, periodicity

Is it possible to include the start and end index values in when using the `rolling` function in `pandas` such that the values of the series are periodic?

For example, I have the following `Series` instance:

```
import pandas as pd
timestamps = [1, 2, 3, 4]
quantities = [1, 16, 9, 4]
series = pd.Series(quantities, index=timestamps)
```

which when I type:

```
series.rolling(window=3, min_periods=3, center=True).median()
```

yields:

```
1    NaN
2    9.0
3    9.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

However, I'd like to include either ends of the series in the calculation such that the result is:

```
1    median([4, 1, 16])   4.0
2    median([1, 16, 9])   9.0
3    median([16, 9, 4])   9.0
4    median([9, 4, 1])    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Thanks for any help trying to achieve this!

Comment: Would make more sense if the last one was `9, 4, 1`

Comment: @Erfan yep, and correct :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extend the list with the first and last element and then calculate the rolling median. After that we `dropna` and assign the series back

Wont win the price for most beautiful code, but it does the job. Could not think of another way.

```
quantities2 = quantities.copy()
quantities2.insert(0, quantities2[-1])
quantities2.insert(len(quantities2), quantities2[0])
print(quantities2)

[4, 1, 16, 9, 4, 4]
```

```
series = pd.Series(quantities2)
series = pd.Series(series.rolling(window=3, min_periods=3, center=True).median().dropna(), index=timestamps)

print(series)
1    4.0
2    9.0
3    9.0
4    4.0
dtype: float64
```

But then again, do we have to write [cleanest code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29170/do-you-actually-write-clean-code) :)